# How to use the git branch as build nr in AppVeyor

Tags: git, github, appveyor

In AppVeyor I would like to setup the build number with the release number from Github. That would be used for the AssemblyVersion patching.

I am using GitFlow, and have a release branch. In SourceTree I create a new Release, for example v1.2, which creates the branch release/v1.2.
The 1.2 part I would like to use in AppVeyor.

Like, Build version format:{gitRelease}.{build}

[image: Screenshot AppVeyor build nr]

for this to work,

1. I need to retrieve the gitHub branch name,
2. Extract the release number from it,
3. Put that in a variable {gitRelease}
4. Run this before the assemblyVersion patching

But I cannot find how to do this.

For the build itself I have a build script, to sent the output (nuget package) to Octopus Deploy, so that means there is no Before build script section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from the Support Staff from AppVeyor, I got it working.
[1733-how-to-call-the-assemblyversion-patch-from-the-build-script](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/1733-how-to-call-the-assemblyversion-patch-from-the-build-script)

I have to use the init section in the appveyor.yml.
And I used a seperate cmd line for the UpdateBuild - version (I had some trouble with the qoutes).

```
init:
- cmd: "set appVeyorBuildVersion=%appveyor_build_version%\necho appVeyorBuildVersion:%appVeyorBuildVersion% \n\nset branch=%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%\necho branch:%branch%\n\nset gitVersion=%branch:~-3%\necho gitversion:%gitVersion%\n\nset newVersion=%gitVersion%.%APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER%\necho %newVersion%\n\n"
- cmd: appveyor UpdateBuild -Version "%newVersion%"

assembly_info:
  patch: true
  file: '**\AssemblyInfo.*'
  assembly_version: '{version}'
  assembly_file_version: '{version}'
  assembly_informational_version: '{version}'
build_script:
- cmd: "echo Building version:%appveyor_build_version%"
- cmd: "nuget restore\nmsbuild MySolution.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Release"
```

The command line part (better readable):

```
echo repo branch:%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%

set branch=%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%
echo branch:%branch%

set gitVersion=%branch:~-4%
echo gitversion:%gitVersion%


set newVersion=%gitVersion%.%APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER%
echo %newVersion%

appveyor UpdateBuild -Version "%newVersion%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab version number from environment variable, process it and send back using AppVeyor build worker API:

```
$version = $env:appveyor_build_version
# ... do something with it
Update-AppveyorBuild -Version $version
```

Comment: This get the version form AppVeyor. What I want is to get the version from GitHub (from the branch name).

Comment: I can get the gitVersion now, and build up the version I want to use:

    set gitVersion=%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH:~-4%
    set version=%gitVersion%.%APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER%

The AppVeyorBuild can be updated with this, as you mentioned. But how to call the AssemblyVersion patch?